Check digit algorithm to detect two mistakes
I use Damm algorithm to produce a check digit of a number inputted by a user. It produces a different digit if the number was typed by the user with a single mistake.
However now I want to extend it to detect two typos. I am ok if there are two check digits required for this.
How can I achieve this with Damm or any other algorithm?

How about modulo 97? It's also used in international bank account numbers.

You tagged computer-science: check out CS@SE.

I can also remove the tag. I don’t understand how using a specific tag should lead to closing a question.

To detect 2 errors in a string, there must be a minimum Hamming distance of 3 between any two valid strings.
